# do-release-upgrade -d Ubuntu 13.10 -> 14.04 failing

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

Ubuntu 13.10 64 server, after doing one upgrade from 13.04 -> 13.10 then attempting 13.10 -> 14.04. I had a transient network failure downloading package lists for 14.04 once which stopped the process, trying to restart the process results in the following

```
root@server:~# do-release-upgrade -d

Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [198 B]
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,148 kB]
Fetched 1,148 kB in 0s (0 B/s)
authenticate 'trusty.tar.gz' against 'trusty.tar.gz.gpg'
gpg exited 2
Debug information:

gpg: fatal: can't open fd 6 for status output: Bad file descriptor
secmem usage: 0/0 bytes in 0/0 blocks of pool 0/0


Authentication failed
Authenticating the upgrade failed. There may be a problem with the network or with the server.
```

How can I restart the do-release-upgrade process?

Apt-get has been fully updated, upgraded, dist-upgraded.

Update:

```
root@server:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
Release:        13.10
Codename:       saucy
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This answer is almost off-topic, but something what I've been wondering.

Every time I upgrade Debian or some of its derivates, such as Ubuntu or Mint, I just do

```
sed -i -e 's/olddistroname/newdistroname/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade
reboot
```

And then I enjoy my new, just released distro.

This has worked for me since forever. All this `do-release-upgrade` hoopla makes me a very confused, angry, old-beard.

So my sub-question is: what is the benefit of those `do-release-upgrade` style commands if they don't even work? What's wrong with the proven, working way? (apt-get versus aptitude is another fight I'm just trying to digest)

Comment: Agreed it is off-topic, however it has resolved the problem. System is now upgraded. I don't know why I didn't think of this myself! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the same error was caused (as suggested in the error output) by the repositories for my release (13.04) being unavailable. This in turn was due to 13.04 just not being supported any longer. (You easily notice this by the failure of `apt-get update`.) It seems like in such a case you can not `do-release-upgrade` but actually have to add some repositories which provide the new packages (e.g. just replace old by new release name in /etc/apt/sources.list) and then `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade` as suggested by Janne. (This way also the package signatures are verified, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

First do `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to clean up anything you broke, followed by `sudo apt-get update` to update your sources, then try again. Keep in mind `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` should be used with caution and certainly should not be used in production environments.

EDIT:

According to upgrade [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TrustyUpgrades) you can directly upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 ("Trusty Tahr") from Ubuntu 13.10 ("Saucy Salamander") without the `-d` option. You should be able to solve this by executing `sudo do-release-upgrade`

Comment: Tried exactly as suggested. This has not fixed the "gpg: fatal: can't open fd 6 for status output: Bad file descriptor" error. Output of do-release-upgrade remains exactly as described above.

Comment: Make sure your system is current with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` first.

Comment: Unfortunately this is all up to date: 
    apt-get dist-upgrade
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    Calculating upgrade... Done
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: could you please include a copy of your `sudo lsb_release -a` for me.

Comment: Updated as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 40976EAF437D05B5
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
```

This downloads the missing GPG keys (as mentioned in the original error message) from the Ubuntu GPG keyserver.

Comment: At is not enough, give some explanation, too.

Comment: This worked for me